# Calculate working minutes between two timestamps

Tags: python, python-2.x, datetime, pandas

I've created a function to calculate the working minutes between two timestamps.

I class working minutes as those between 9am - 5pm and not on weekends or national holidays.

The holidays are those in the UK.

I think the function itself is quite quick, although generating the initial series probably takes a bit of time.

Because the working dates are fixed, I might just put them into a database table and load them each time the function is called, probably a bit faster.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from pandas.tseries.holiday import Holiday, AbstractHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CDay

class HolidayCalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules =[Holiday('Xmas Day generic',month=12,day=25),
            Holiday('NYD generic',month=1,day=1),
            Holiday('Boxing Day generic',month=12,day=26),
            Holiday('Good Friday 2015',year=2015,month=4,day=3),
            Holiday('Easter Monday 2015',year=2015,month=4,day=6),
            Holiday('May Bank Holiday 2015',year=2015,month=5,day=4),
            Holiday('Spring Bank Holiday 2015',year=2015,month=5,day=25),
            Holiday('Summer Bank Holiday 2015',year=2015,month=8,day=31),
            Holiday('Boxing Day 2015',year=2015,month=12,day=28),
            Holiday('Good Friday 2016',year=2016,month=3,day=25),
            Holiday('Easter Monday 2016',year=2016,month=3,day=28),
            Holiday('May Bank 2016',year=2016,month=5,day=2),
            Holiday('Spring Bank 2016',year=2016,month=5,day=30),
            Holiday('Summer Bank 2016',year=2016,month=8,day=29),
            Holiday('Boxing Day 2016',year=2016,month=12,day=26),
            Holiday('Xmas Day 2016',year=2016,month=12,day=27),
            Holiday('NYD 2017',year=2017,month=1,day=2),
            Holiday('Good Friday 2017',year=2017,month=4,day=14),
            Holiday('Easter Monday 2017',year=2017,month=4,day=17),
            Holiday('May Bank 2017',year=2017,month=5,day=1),
            Holiday('Spring Bank 2017',year=2017,month=5,day=29),
            Holiday('Summer Bank 2017',year=2017,month=8,day=28)]

cal = HolidayCalendar()

dayindex = pd.bdate_range(datetime.date(2015,1,1),datetime.date.today(),freq=CDay(calendar=cal))

day_series = dayindex.to_series()

def count_mins(start,end):

    starttime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(start)/1000)

    endtime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(end)/1000)

    days = day_series[starttime.date():endtime.date()]

    daycount = len(days)

    if daycount == 0:
        return daycount
    else:
        startday = datetime.datetime(days[0].year,
                                 days[0].month,
                                 days[0].day,
                                 hour=9,
                                 minute=0)
        endday = datetime.datetime(days[-1].year,
                               days[-1].month,
                               days[-1].day,
                               hour=17,
                               minute=0)
        if daycount == 1:  

            if starttime < startday:
                periodstart = startday
            else:
                periodstart = starttime
            if endtime > endday:
                periodend = endday
            else:
                periodend = endtime

            return (periodend - periodstart).seconds/60

        if daycount == 2:

            if starttime < startday:
                first_day_mins = 480
            else:
                first_day_mins = (startday.replace(hour=17)-starttime).seconds/60
            if endtime > endday:
                second_day_mins = 480
            else:
                second_day_mins = (endtime-endday.replace(hour=9)).seconds/60

            return (first_day_mins + second_day_mins)

        else:

            if starttime < startday:
                first_day_mins = 480
            else:
                first_day_mins = (startday.replace(hour=17)-starttime).seconds/60
            if endtime > endday:
                second_day_mins = 480
            else:
                second_day_mins = (endtime-endday.replace(hour=9)).seconds/60

            return (first_day_mins + second_day_mins + ((daycount-2)*480))
```

---

Building on the advice from Graipher, I've settled on the below:

```
def count_mins(start,end):

    starttime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(start)/1000)

    endtime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(end)/1000)

    days = day_series[starttime.date():endtime.date()]

    daycount = len(days)

    if not days:
        return 0
    else:
        startday = days[0].replace(hour=9, minute=0)

        endday = days[-1].replace(hour=17, minute=0)

        if daycount == 1:

            periodstart = max(startday, starttime)

            periodend = min(endday, endtime)

            return (periodend - periodstart).seconds/60

        if daycount == 2:

            first_day_mins = min(480, ((startday.replace(hour=17)-starttime).seconds/60))

            second_day_mins = min(480, ((endtime-endday.replace(hour=9)).seconds/60))

            return (first_day_mins + second_day_mins)

        else:

            first_day_mins = min(480, ((startday.replace(hour=17)-starttime).seconds/60))

            last_day_mins = min(480, ((endtime-endday.replace(hour=9)).seconds/60))

            return (first_day_mins + last_day_mins + ((daycount-2)*480))
```

Comment: @Graipher - see my comment on your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

### Avoid magic numbers

The number 480 (number of minutes in a working day) appears repeatedly. Promote it to a `CONSTANT`.

### Superflous `else`

The following code can be shortened:

```
if cond:
    return
else:
    pass
```

to:

```
if cond:
    return
pass
```

### Tuple assignment

You can use tuple assignment to get rid of some redundancy:

```
starttime, endtime = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(t)/1000) for t in (start, end))
```

### Reduce logic

Your comparing logic can be greatly reduce.

First, note that:

```
if starttime < startday:
    periodstart = startday
else:
    periodstart = starttime
```

is equivalent to:

```
periodstart = max(starttime, startday)
```

Also the case for 1, 2 and more than 2 days are very similar. For the secon `(daycount-2)*480` is just zero, for the first it is `-1`.

Also `if daycount == 0` might be better written as `if not days`, since an empty list evaluates as false. This allows us to get rid of the variable `daycount`, since it is only needed once now.

With these few changes I arrive at (omitting the setup code for the holidays for brevity):

```
FULL_WORKDAY = 480  # min


def count_mins(start, end):
    starttime, endtime = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(t)/1000) for t in (start, end))
    days = day_series[starttime.date():endtime.date()]
    if not days:
        return 0
    first_day_mins = min(FULL_WORKDAY, (days[0].replace(hour9, minute=0, second=0) - starttime).seconds/60)
    last_day_mins = min(FULL_WORKDAY, (endtime - days[-1].replace(hour=17, minute=0, second=0)).seconds/60)
    return first_day_mins + (len(days)-2)*FULL_WORKDAY + last_day_mins
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I can see that your improvements would shorten my code dramatically. However, your logic contains an error. `startday` and `endday` should not be the same _date_ as `starttime` and `endtime`; what if the latter are on a weekend? For example, with a `start` argument of 1468671650000 and an `end` argument of 1468833650000, you will get a wrong answer (should be 80).

Comment: I'm sure it will. That's a much more succint way of writing `startday` and `endday` though, so I'll steal it!

Comment: That's true, although I don't think that writing the function in that way will make it any faster (will it?) and certainly doesn't help the readability. Therefore, my final function would be as above.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat. You can always add intermediate variables back in.